# How to use ls command output in rm for a particular directory

Tags: linux, find, ls, rm

I want to delete oldest files in a directory when the number of files is greater than 5. I'm using

> (ls -1t | tail -n 3)

to get the oldest 3 files in the directory. This works exactly as I want. Now I want to delete them in a single command with rm. As I'm running these commands on a Linux server, cd into the directory and deleting is not working so I need to use either find or ls with rm and delete the oldest 3 files. Please help out.
Thanks :)

Comment: _cd into the directory and deleting is not working_ - how's that? `ls -1t` also only operates on the current directory, so since that works, it must already be in the right directory.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to delete files from some arbitrary directory, then pass the directory name into the `ls` command.  The default is to use the current directory.

Then use `$()` parameter expansion to transfer the result of `tail` into `rm` like this

```
rm $(ls -1t dirname| tail -n 3)
```

Comment: I want to delete in a a particular directory, can't I pass directory name to the rm cmd? some like : `rm <dir_name_where _it_has_to_delete> $(ls -1t <files_location>| tail -n 3)`

Comment: if i use cd <dir_name> && rm $(ls -1t | tail -n 3), then it says no such directory. They're zip files and its not getting deleted.

Comment: I have updated the answer so that you can delete files from any directory.

Comment: what would happen if `ls` returns `No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

```
rm $(ls -1t | tail -n 3) 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Why do you redirect the *stderr*? Why not `rm -f`?

Answer (score 0):

`ls` may return `No such file or directory` error message, which may cause `rm` to run unnessesary with that value.

With the help of following answer: [find - suppress "No such file or directory" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45575053/2402577) and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140647/198423

```
find $dirname -type d -exec ls -1t {} + | tail -n 3 | xargs rm -rf
```