# find - suppress "No such file or directory" errors

Tags: bash, unix, find

I can use `-s` in `grep` to suppress errors, but I don't see an equivalent for the `find` command in the man page... Is the only option to redirect STDERR>/dev/null?

Or is there an option that handles this? (open to fancy `awk` and `perl` solutions if needed)

Example:

```
$ for dir in `ls /mnt/16_c/`; do find /mnt/16_c/$dir/data/ -mtime +180 -type f -exec echo {} \;; done
find: `/mnt/16_c/test_container/dat/': No such file or directory
```

Comment: What's wrong with redirecting stderr? Why do you want to use external tools like awk and perl? Without knowing what's the problem, it's difficult to propose solutions

Comment: You could test if the directory exists before calling find `test -d /mnt/16_c/$dir/data/ && find ....` so no need to redirect at all

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can redirect `stderr` with `2>/dev/null`, for example:

```
find /mnt/16_c/$dir/data/ -mtime +180 -type f -exec echo {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

Btw, the code in your question can be replaced with:

```
find /mnt/16_c/*/data/ -mtime +180 -type f 2>/dev/null
```

And if there is at least one matching directory,
then you don't even need to suppress `stderr`,
because `find` will only search in directories that match this pattern.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about the fact that the wildcard would prevent this!

Comment: What happens if something goes wrong inside the `-exec` part? I don't want to supress such a error.

Answer (score 4):

I know this isn't exactly what you asked, but my typical approach is to `find` a path that definitely exists, then use the `-path` flag to filter.

So instead of `find /home/not-a-path`, which raises an error, I would do `find /home -path "/home/not-a-path/*"`, which doesn't raise an error.

I had to do this because when I would stream a failed `find` to `/dev/null` in a `make` file, the error would still cause the command to crash. The approach I described above works though.

Comment: -path takes a pattern so the command should be `find /home -path "/home/not-a-path/*"`