# find -exec - suppress errors only for find, but not for executed command

Tags: bash, find, exec, stderr

When running the `find` command, it may output "No such file or directory" errors.

As answered to the [find - suppress "No such file or directory" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45575053/7939871) question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45575053/7939871, redirecting file descriptor 2 to `/dev/null` will happily silences error messages from `find`, such as `No such file or directory`:

```sh
find yada-yada... 2>/dev/null
```

This is perfectly fine, as long as not using `-exec` to execute a command. Because `2>/dev/null` will also silence errors from the executed command.

As an example:

```sh
$ find /root -exec sh -c 'echo "Error" >&2' {} \; 2>/dev/null
$ find /root -exec sh -c 'echo "Error" >&2' {} \;
Error
find: ‘/root’: Permission denied
```

Is there a way to silence errors from `find` while preserving errors from the executed command?

Comment: you might have to use `find -print0 2> /dev/null | xargs -0` instead of `find -exec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `-exec` option in `find` command is integration of [`xargs`](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/xargs-command) command into `find` command.

You can alwayes separate `find` from `-exec` by piping `find` output into `xargs` command.

For example:

```
 find / -type f -name "*.yaml" -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs  ls -l
```

Comment: maybe `xargs -0`, but this is still different from `find -exec` and even more from `find -execdir` as the command will be executed even when nothing has been found.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you can't use:

```sh
find . -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 ...
```

Then here's a POSIX way to do the same thing:

```sh
find . -exec sh -c '"$0" "$@" 2>&3' ... {} + 3>&2 2>/dev/null
```

<sup>**note:** `3>&2` is located **before** `2>/dev/null`</sup>